# (Android) Navigation drawer items working only in one activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have 7 activities in my app. Every activity extends a "Base activity". This "Base" has a method that generates the navigation items from my database.

For example:

```
public class ActivityA extends ActivityBase{}

public class ActivityB extends ActivityBase{}
```

And this is the ActivityBase:

```
public class ActivityBase extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{}
```

Within this ActivityBase I have:

1. Get items from database

   ```
   generateDrawerItems(){}
   ```
2. Each item action

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      int id = item.getItemId();
      if (id == 1) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
         startActivity(intent);
      }
      if (id == 2) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
         startActivity(intent);
      }
     ...
   }
   ```

Everything works perfectly on my MainActivity, but in any other activity, although all items are generate from "generateDrawerItems" method correctly, the "onNavigationItemSelected" method is not called. In other words, every activity has the navigationDrawer but only on the MainActivity the "touch action" works.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, when you start an other Activity from the drawerlayaout you lose the established link of the layout with the MainActivity.

Do you create the DrawerLayout for every Activity once you started it ?

Also, I think starting an activity for every item of our drawerlayout will be hard to adapt on large screen devices. You should check out the [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) interaction with a drawerlayout which will solve your problem AND allow your app better large screen support.

**EDIT**

To do so, you need your MainActivity which defines the DrawerLayout and contain a Fragment (it will be your 1st view on activity launch). And one fragment for every items on your DrawerLayout.

To change the content :

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

   if (id == R.id.nav_item1) {
      FragOne fragment = new FragOne();
      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_item2) {
      FragTwo fragment = new FragTwo();
      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
 }
  ...
}
```

The drawer will stay in place on every Fragment. You can find an example of the XML logic in Android studio templates.

Comment: You mean the XML? Yes, every activity has android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout as the root element.
About this fragment interaction with the DrawerLayout , I never did that before. Do you have an example?

Comment: Thanks Simon! I'll try that.

Comment: Edited the main answer because I was limited by characters number.

Comment: This looks really nice. But I would have to "convert" all my activities (except the main, of course) into fragments, that's a lot of work, I don't know if I have time for that.

Comment: It depends how much code you have in every of your Activity. Most of the thing in the Activity onCreate() can move to Fragment onCreateView(). But Yes, it will take some time to adapt.

Comment: Thanks Simon! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I did it. Wasn't that hard. Thanks a lot Simon!

Comment: Well done. The view logic should be really clear before starting to code the layout logic to avoid such a change. I did the same mistake the 1st time. The best way to learn is always to try and make some mistakes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going on. What Simon said works perfectly, but if you are having the same problem I had, maybe this works for you.

The problem is that the drawer touch action was working only on one activity. I stoped and tried to figured out what the difference from the other ones. I found out that the element *"android.support.design.widget.NavigationView"* should be the last element inside the *"android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout"*,
I just change it and now it works. I don't know why is that, if someone know please tell us.